flutter_inappwebview refused to connect in Flutter web
I want to build an app for web only with Flutter. It works fine when I load "https://flutter.dev", but when I change the URL to "https://www.google.com" then I get a "connection refused" error.
Following image is the error response: connection_refused
I've also tried the "webview_flutter_web" library, but I'm facing the same error.
I've attached my code below.
InAppWebView(
          key: webViewKey,
          initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
            url: WebUri("https://www.google.com"),
          ),
          onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest: (controller, challenge) async {
            return ServerTrustAuthResponse(
              action: ServerTrustAuthResponseAction.PROCEED,
            );
          },
          onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
            webViewController = controller;
            setState(() {
              progress = 1;
              this.url = url.toString();
            });
          },
          initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
  crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
    useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
  )),
          onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
            webViewController = controller;
          },
          onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
            setState(() {
              this.url = url.toString();
            });
          },
          androidOnPermissionRequest: (controller, origin, resources) async {
            return PermissionRequestResponse(resources: resources, action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
          },
          onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {},
          onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
            if (progress == 100) {}
            setState(() {
              this.progress = progress / 100;
            });
          },
          onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
            setState(() {
              this.url = url.toString();
            });
          },
          onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {},
          shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
            var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;

            if (!["http", "https", "file", "chrome", "data", "javascript", "about"].contains(uri.scheme)) {
              if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
                await launchUrl(uri);
                return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
              }
            }

            return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
          },
        ),

I've tried flutter_inappwebview and webview_flutter_web, but I'm facing "connection refused" issue. Suggest me a solution so I can run my URL to webview.
